# How to translate Jupyter Notebook code to display a video to "regular" Python script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to "translate" [this code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/movinet.ipynb) from Jupyter Notebook to a "regular" Python script (I mean, using a regular text editor and compiling in server). My problem is in the last line. In the notebook there's this line:

```
media.show_video(plot_video, fps=3)
```

This function displays the video in the script. I want to do the same in my "regular" version (display the video). `plot_video` is a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. If I print looks like this:

```
[[[[255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]
   ...
   [255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]]

  [[255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]
   ...
   [255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]]

  [[255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]
   ...
   [255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]
   [255 255 255]]

  ...
```

Which function can do this or how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV to display the video in a Python script. To install OpenCV do:

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Then, you can create a function that displays the video using OpenCV's `cv2.imshow()`. For example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def display_video(frames, fps=3):
    window_name = 'Video'
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    for frame in frames:
        cv2.imshow(window_name, frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(int(1000 / fps)) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Finally, try this code doing:

```
plot_video = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8) # Replace with your actual video array
display_video(plot_video, fps=3)
```